# Regex - Input Checker Class - Lambda with two lists

Tags: c#, regex, lambda

I have an input checker class with some RegExes, and I have converted some of the loops to lambdas. Am I doing it right? They seem to work fine, but I'm new to Lambdas. Does this offer a performance benefit over the commented implementation? Should I try implementing the first one as a lambda, and if so, how? Thanks in advance!

```
public static class DataChecker
{
    public static bool IsGameInputDataValid(string[] dataFile)
    {
        if (dataFile.Length < 5)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var regexList = new List<Regex>();
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d\\s\\d$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^(\\d,\\d )*(\\d,\\d)$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d\\s\\d$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d \\d [NESW]{1}$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^[RLM]{1}( [RLM]{1})*$"));

        //cant figure this one out as lambda... but should it even be converted for performance reasons?
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (!regexList[i].IsMatch(dataFile[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        var listOfMoves = dataFile.Select(x => x).Skip(4).ToList();
        //instead of:
        // for (int i = 4; i<countOfLinesInInputFile; i++)
        // {
        //     listOfMoves.Add(lines[i]);
        // }

        var areaAnyMoveSequencesInvalid =
            listOfMoves.Select(x => regexList[4].IsMatch(x)).ToList()
            .Any(y => y == false);

        if (areaAnyMoveSequencesInvalid)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // instead of:
        // foreach (var line in listOfMoves)
        // {
        //     if (!regexList[4].IsMatch(line))
        //     {
        //         return false;
        //     }
        // }

        return true;
    }
}
```

edit: Originally I wanted the question to only focus on the lambdas, but I got a lot of responses for the RegExes as well. Therefore I'll add the missing parts to make sense of that. It's a turtle-moving game in 2-dimensional x,y coordinates map.

Sample data file:

```
5 4
1,1 1,3 3,3
4 2
0 1 N
R M L M M
R M M M
M R M M M M
M R M M
M M M
```

Rules:
The first line should define the board size
• The second line should contain a list of mines (i.e. list of co-ordinates separated by a space)
• The third line of the file should contain the exit point.
• The fourth line of the file should contain the starting position of the turtle.
• The fifth line to the end of the file should contain a series of moves.

Where:
R: Rotate right
L: Rotate left
M: Move
N,E,S,W: cardinal directions

I've updated the original with d+ instead of d, to allow for multiple digit coordinates:

```
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d+\\s\\d+$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^(\\d+,\\d+ )*(\\d+,\\d+)$|^$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d+\\s\\d+$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d+ \\d+ [NESW]{1}$"));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^[RLM]{1}( [RLM]{1})*$"));
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Site. The question title should tell us what the code does rather than what your concerns about the code are. It would also be helpful if there was a short paragraph explaining what the code does, this helps us provide a better review and better suggestions. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), it can give you some hints on the title and other good tips for getting up votes on your question. You might also want to remove any commented out code because that type of code makes us question if the code is ready

Comment: perhaps given us a sample of `dataFile` and explaination on what the expressions do and what data do you consider `Valid`. This would give us some idea on your question and we can help you with that.

Comment: Please don't ignore comments that advise you to improve your post in any way, @pacmaninbw suggested something because those are the traits of a good question. I have edited the title for you now

Comment: Hi! Sorry for getting back to the thread a little late and thanks so much for all the replies! The original idea was to not put the emphasis on reviewing the regexes for, but the lambdas -- I only included the regexes so you can see what I'm working with later on. However, I'll edit the post now because of the replies :)

Comment: Please do not update your question after you have received answers: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers I've rolled back your edit. If you want to post a follow-up question, you can do so.

Comment: @BCdotWEB The original post was still available after the edit, the edit only provided more information requested by the answers... I think it would be clearer for people coming to the thread with the edit approved, although true, that not necessary for the original question. However, someone also edited the original title, so now the answer to the original question is not easily findable (lambdas), because someone edited it out... I feel moderation is going too far with this one, but if you feel it's okay this way...

Comment: @user3616457 I thought I saw your edit also updated some of the original code, if that isn't the case then you can re-apply your edit.

Comment: @BCdotWEB You are right, it did update the original RegExes, albeit in a very minor way, and not related to the main question. I've included it properly at the end now, instead of modifying the original one. Thanks!

Comment: You've added a lot to the question and it shows up on some monitoring tools. I don't see where you might have invalidated the answers which is what we worry about the most. It might be better in the future to ask a new question with a link to the old question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would tackle this problem by not adding the last regex to the list but to have this as a separate regex. Using a little "trick" by using [`Enumerable.Range()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netcore-3.1) you can replace the `for` with a linq expression like so

```
if (Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Any(i => !regexList[i].IsMatch(dataFile[i]))) { return false; }
```

After the loop you have this line

```
var listOfMoves = dataFile.Select(x => x).Skip(4).ToList();
```

in which you neither need the call to `Select()` nor to `ToList()`.

In the next line

```
var areaAnyMoveSequencesInvalid =
            listOfMoves.Select(x => regexList[4].IsMatch(x)).ToList()
            .Any(y => y == false);
```

A simple call to `Any()` would be sufficient but you could just return the value of a call to `All()` instead like shown below.

If the method in question is called quite often you should consider to use compiled regex. They take a little bit more time to create them but executing them will become faster. If you take this way you should initialize the regexes in the static constructor.

Summing this up will lead to

```
public static class DataChecker
{
    static DataChecker()
    {
        regexList = new List<Regex>();
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d\\s\\d$", RegexOptions.Compiled));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^(\\d,\\d )*(\\d,\\d)$", RegexOptions.Compiled));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d\\s\\d$", RegexOptions.Compiled));
        regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d \\d [NESW]{1}$", RegexOptions.Compiled));

        lastRegex = new Regex("^[RLM]{1}( [RLM]{1})*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }
    private static readonly List<Regex> regexList;
    private static readonly Regex lastRegex;
    public static bool IsGameInputDataValid(string[] dataFile)
    {
        if (dataFile.Length < 5) { return false; }

        if (Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Any(i => !regexList[i].IsMatch(dataFile[i]))) { return false; }

        return dataFile.Skip(4).All(x => lastRegex.IsMatch(x));
    }
}
```

Without knowing what the input looks like I can't come up with a better name for the last regex. In addition this isn't tested but should work like a charme.

Comment: The first 4 Regex's are the mystery to me.  The last one is a way to validate a "move".

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much! I've added a sample file and the rules for the regexes for more clarification.

Answer (score 3):

When working with the `Regex` pattern, you can benefit from the "[verbatim string literal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)" operator `@`:

so that

`"^\\d\\s\\d$"` becomes `@"^\d\s\d$"`

This is more readable and if you're using Visual Studio, you will get help from intellisense (a better coloring), when designing the pattern directly in place of `new Regex(pattern)`

---

Besides that, I'd go with the suggestions by Heslacher, but take it a step further:

```
  public static class DataCheckerReview
  {
    static readonly List<Regex> headerPatterns;
    static readonly Regex movePattern;

    static DataCheckerReview()
    {
      headerPatterns = new List<Regex>
      {
        new Regex(@"^\d\s\d$", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^(\d,\d )*(\d,\d)$", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\d\s\d$", RegexOptions.Compiled),
        new Regex(@"^\d \d [NESW]$", RegexOptions.Compiled)
      };

      movePattern = new Regex(@"^[RLM]( [RLM])*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }

    static bool LinesEnough(string[] dataLines) => dataLines != null && dataLines.Length > 4;
    static bool CheckHeaders(string[] dataLines) => headerPatterns.Zip(dataLines).All(pair => pair.First.IsMatch(pair.Second));
    static bool CheckMoves(string[] dataLines) => dataLines.Skip(4).All(dl => movePattern.IsMatch(dl));

    public static bool IsGameInputDataValid(string[] dataLines)
    {
      return LinesEnough(dataLines) && CheckHeaders(dataLines) && CheckMoves(dataLines);
    }
  }
```

When initializing a list "statically" as you do, you can do it as shown above instead of calling `Add()` for each entry (You can use this approach for all objects that provides an `Add()` method and implements `IEnumerable`).
If you don't add or remove entries in the list, a plain array may be a better choice than a list?

In `CheckHeaders()` the `Zip()` extension is used to pair each regex in the header patterns with the first four lines in the input lines. `Zip()` only pairs items in the sets for the count of items in the shortest set, so no need for `Take()` etc.

By abstracting the validation of the input away in dedicated methods, you get a clean design, that is easy to maintain and the naming makes it easy to understand what each step does.

The context is somewhat unclear, but just returning bool from a method that checks several properties is not very informative. I think, I'd throw a dedicated exception if a step fails or at least have some kind of logging. As a client of the method, it would be nice to know what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestions, sounds like some valid points there!

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer: Not a Code Reviewer

- Just looking into the regular expressions here!
- Not sure exactly what we are doing.
- My guess is that:

We would probably want:

```
    regexList.Add(new Regex("^(?:\\d,\\d )*(?:\\d,\\d)$"));
```

instead of

```
    regexList.Add(new Regex("^(\\d,\\d )*(\\d,\\d)$"));
```

and we don't want the `{1}`:

```
    regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d \\d [NESW]$"));
    regexList.Add(new Regex("^[RLM]( [RLM])*$"));
```

and maybe we would want non-capturing groups here too, instead of capturing groups:

```
    regexList.Add(new Regex("^\\d \\d [NESW]$"));
    regexList.Add(new Regex("^[RLM](?: [RLM])*$"));
```

and that'd a bit simplify the expressions.

#### Happy Coding! ( ˆ_ˆ )

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the RegExes! :) I originally did not want to focus on the regexes much, but I have added some clarifications to the OP for them now. I agree about the non-capturing groups (According to StackOverflow, it should make a difference performance-wise (albeit small in this case)). The {1} is needed due to the rules I've just posted I believe.